# C# projects not listed in Visual Studio Express for Web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I have read on some forums that Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web contains C# projects.
So, I downloaded VS2013 from [this site](https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/review?download=true&family=VisualStudioExpressWeb&release=VisualStudio2013Upd4&type=web&slcid=0x409&context=eyJwZSI6MSwicGMiOjEsImljIjoxLCJhbyI6MCwiYW0iOjAsIm9wIjpudWxsLCJhZCI6MSwiZmEiOjAsImF1IjpudWxsLCJjdiI6NDczODQ4ODM1LCJmcyI6MCwic3UiOjAsImVyIjoxfQ2)

But there were just Visual Basic projects. 
Can anyone tell me if there is another edition of VS for Web that contains c# projects or how to add C# projects to my version

Answer (score 0):

You can download vs express 2013 for web and desktop from the following link.
Its free.
[vs express 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaUlD.jpg)

For me its showing both VB ans VC#,
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I downloaded it from here

Comment: @porandddr Is it possible that I don't have c# projects because I also have VS2013 for Desktop installed?

Comment: If you wants to create web based applications, then you can use vs express for web. If you wants to create windows applications, then go for vs express for desktop. Both VB and VC# is available in vs express 2013

Answer (score 0):

I repaired the VS2013 through Control Panel and c# projects appeared. I don't know if this will solve the problem for everyone, but it worked for me.